# Difference between JSX and Babel in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I am starting to use ReactJS.

In the [Hello World template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html), it includes a `babel.min.js` file but it also includes JSX syntax to render a component.

**What is the relationship or difference between JSX and Babel?**

Comment: JSX is JavaScript xml which is mostly same as html but it’s not html. Browser don’t understand jsx directly so someone has to transpile jsx to native JavaScript so Babel does that. It’s a transpiler

Comment: Babel is what transpiles the JSX into plain JS so that the browser can read and execute it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel is a transpiler that transforms JSX into JavaScript so that the browser is capable of rendering the application since it doesn't understand JSX. JSX is basically syntactic sugar for React.createElement (why not use this method then? well its cumbersome writting it in this way and its really hard to manage and debug the app so therefore JSX comes into play). JSX represents components in an Markup fashion, even though they look like HTML in most of the cases.